# Portable Monitors for MacBook Pro?

Tags: display

I'm looking for a Portable Monitors for my macbook pro (possibily a 14'')
Do you happen to know some model that is working on a mac?

I found this [one](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1840/2/) (ThinkVision LT1421) but it does not work completely.

Comment: The article you linked to says the monitor did work with a MacBook Pro. Why do you say it does not work completely?

Comment: Because the article is not accurate. If you go to the controller site for the apple driver you'll see that it does not support OSX completely.

Comment: There used to be a displaylink software solution using an iPad as a monitor over wifi.  Unfortunately not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the latest [DisplayLink manager](http://www.displaylink.com/support/mac_downloads.php) software? It is a bit of a battery-guzzler and has some limitations r.e. 3D acceleration, but may be an improvement on the native OS X driver.

Comment: I still need to buy a monitor. :)

Comment: I think the only 14" choices you have are the ThinkVision and this Toshiba:(http://us.toshiba.com/computers/accessories/mobile-monitor/). You're stuck with 1366x768 or 1280x800 unless you step up to 22" or so, if resolution is an issue. This AOC (http://www.amazon.com/AOC-E1649FWU-USB-Powered-Portable-Monitor/dp/B005SEZR0G) has been reported as working fairly effortlessly in OS X, so that may be worth a look.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I don't need specifically a 14''. I mean as long as it's not a 20+''. This AOC seems interesting but apparently in not available on amazon.co.uk

Comment: The AOC seems to be in stock here (http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/AOC-e1649Fwu-16-LED-LCD-Monitor-16-9-16-ms/6195290/product.html?cid=133635). It's £128.45, but that does include the international shipping across the pond to the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Every single USB monitor or video adapter I have ever seen uses the same DisplayLink chip and thus uses the same DisplayLink driver. While the Mac version of the driver does work, it unfortunately leaves much to be desired. So to answer your question... at the time of this writing, no, there is no **USB** monitor that works completely with OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The "Mini Displays" approach from Edovia appears to enable using an iPad as an external monitor (over Wifi), if your Mac runs 10.7 or later.

http://edovia.com/minidisplay/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to figure out what kind of monitor you need. There are many portable ordinary monitors, and there are also monitors that are more like monitors attached to both sides of the screen. Two screens and three screens are called workstations. Go search for tri-screen and you will see what it looks like. For Macbooks, most tri-screens are very useful and effective.

However, some portable monitors may only have the mirroring function and cannot achieve the effect of a secondary screen. You can try the [Duex Max Portable Dual Screen Laptop Monitor](https://www.mobilepixels.us/products/duex-max-portable-dual-screen-laptop-monitor) by Mobile Pixels. I think it will work. Or just browse a store with a wider selection like Uperfect portable monitors, I had a [UGame K118](https://www.uperfectmonitor.com/products/18-inch-144hz-freesync-monitor) and performs pretty well so far.

Comment: Were these solutions available to the OP?

Comment: With which Mac model have you used the monitors you are recommending?

Comment: I've only tried connecting it a few times on my MacBook Pro 14-inch. Usually, I use it to connect my PS5.